# What is the rule for using the words "this" or "that" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I tend to use the word this at the beginning of a sentence when I want to refer to something I said in the previous sentence. For example:

The purpose of a singleton pattern is to allow only one instance of a class. This is beneficial when a program requires only one object to carry out operations for a class.

Grammarly gives me an "intricate text" warning when I use the word "this" instead of "that."

Can someone give me intuition to know which word to use? Thank you.

Comment: "This" is okay, but vague. Here, I'd use *This pattern* or *This instance*.

Comment: Grammarly's "intricate text" warning seems to have more to do with sentence length and number of subordinate clauses than which pronoun you use. I don't see any reason for using "that" rather than "this", but it's probably down to the imperfect way Grammarly's rules are defined (and it's impossible to define perfect rules for something like this)..